# What's the meaning of "For far too many"?

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for **Far too many** expression's meaning.

Phrase I found the word in:

> **For far too many**, the dream has dissipated.

Comment: "For many, the dream has dissipated."  Adding "too" suggests that this "dissipation" would be acceptable below some threshold, but the acceptable threshold has been exceeded.  Further adding "far" suggest that the threshold has been greatly exceeded.

Comment: Also, there is an implied subject, *people* or a similar general grouping of individuals. This also may be a reference back to a previously expressed noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Many* here acts as what traditional grammar calls a "pronoun" and *CGEL* a "fused-head determiner". Both imply that *many* "stands for" itself plus the omitted noun which it modifies, which will be evident in the context. We may assume that the noun is something like "people", or a particular group of people.

*Too* modifies *many* in its ordinary sense of excess: How many people? --*too* many people. And *far* extends *too*: not just a few too many but too many people by a "long distance", by a great amount.

And the whole phrase is the object of the preposition *for*, which indicates the group to which state described in the main clause applies.

> Far too many people find that their dream has dissipated.

Comment: StoneyB, thank you! I've another sentence to show “For far too many”. "But for far too many children, there are not enough reading resources available to them in their native language." This sentence is from here:https://www.google.org/our-work/education/storyweaver/

Comment: @ClockZHONG Here *many* is an ordinary quantifier modifying its head, *children* rather than a quantifier 'fused' with its head; but otherwise the meaning is the same.

Comment: what confused me is  not the "many", it's "far", I've never see using "far" to modify "too" before.

Comment: @ClockZHONG Wth comparatives like *Xer*, *more X*, *too X* it's an intensifying adverb of degree, roughly equivalent to *much* or *very*.