# the charges were "far" too serious

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The judge refused to accept the plea on the grounds that the charges were **far** too serious, with Sharper pleading guilty ...

What does the word "far" meaning in the above sentence? Does it like *so far* (until now) or like *far away*? [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3983696/I-lived-fear-trying-kill-Heartbreaking-impact-statements-Darren-Sharper-victims-read-court-NFL-star-sentenced-20-years-drugging-raping-women.html)

Note: I couldn't understanded from the below answer:

> And far extends too: not just a few too many but too many people by a "long distance", by a great amount. [ell link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63460/whats-the-meaning-of-for-far-too-many)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Far* is used in front of *too* to mean *much*.

You will frequently see expressions such as:

> > far too big...
> >
> > far too salty....
> >
> > far too hot....

all of which mean *much too big/salty/hot.

The words are also used in reverse *too far* to mean *too great a distance*

or in expressions such as:

> > he went too far in his angry response

referring to excessive behaviour.